# How do I parse a Logstash configuration file into JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, logstash

I have a Logstash configuration file in the following format:

```
input {
    twitter {
        keywords => ["apples","bananas",  "cherries",
                       "lettuce", "tomatoes"]
        follows => ["@sirwebber"]
        ... additional parameters ... 
    }
}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        ... similar types of configuration stuff ...
    }
}
```

I would like to parse this into a JSON object in Node.js. So I'm looking for something like:

```
{
    "input": {
        "twitter": {
            "keywords": ["apples","bananas","cherries","lettuce","tomatoes"],
            "follows": ["@sirwebber"],
            ... additional parameters ...                 
        }
    },
    "output": {
       ... similar format ... 
    }
}
```

My first attempt involved reading in the file as a string, and then parsing on new line characters (after splitting on whether I was interested in the input or the output). I then split on '=>', and I was able to create a JavaScript object with the desired keys and values.

This approach works as long as my values do not span multiple lines. However, I want to make sure that the parser works in the general case (which can include spaces between items in an array).

Do you have any advice on what I should do? Do I need to write my own parser? If so, are there any good resources that I should reference on how to write such a parser?

Comment: I don't know logstash configs well enough, but a naive approach would be: 1. replace all occurances of "=>" with ":" 2.  when you encounter the "{" char, if it is preceeded with a char different from ":", prepand ":".

Answer (score 0):

I would tokenize the string based on whitespace, and then run through the tokens:

```
var str = "input {\n\
         twitter {\n\
           keywords => [\"apples\",\"bananas\",\"cherries\"]\n\
           follows => [\"@sirwebber\"]\n\
         }\n\
       }\n\
       \n\
       output {\n\
           elasticsearch {\n\
               something =>\n\
                  [\"hello\"]\n\
           }\n\
       }";

var tokens = str.split(/\s+/);
var js = "{"; 
var prev = '';
for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
    var next = i+1 < tokens.length ? tokens[i+1] : '';
    switch(tokens[i]) {
        case '{':
            js += ":{";
            break;
        case '=>': 
            js += ":";
            break;
        default:
            if (next == "{" || next == '=>') { js += '"'; }
            js += tokens[i] + (((prev == '=>' || prev=='}') && (next != '}' && next != '' && next != '{') )? ',' : '');
            if (next == "{" || next == '=>') { js += '"'; }
            break;
    }
    prev = tokens[i];
}
js += '}';
JSON.parse(js);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This doesn't quite address what I was looking for. In particular, it doesn't work if there are spaces between items in an array, or new line characters. I've updated my question to better show these cases. Thanks again for your help!